# PXELinux with WDS/DNS/DHCP

Tags: linux, windows, windows-server-2012-r2, boot, pxe-boot

I've been reading up on setting up a PXELinux machine to run side by side with WDS on Windows and all the guides talk about setting up a DNS and DHCP server on the same server as the PXELinux.

What I've read is you can run PXELinux and then create a menu that lets you boot over to WDS over PXELinux but how the DHCP and DNS parts confuse me.

My question is there. Do I need to do that even though I have my Windows DNS/DHCP servers or do I need to link them together or do they operate on their own? Little confused as to how all that works out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I understand you correctly, you have a Linux-PXEServer and a Win-Controller with DHCP/DNS?

If it is so, its mostly [simple](http://wiki.r1soft.com/display/CDP3/Configuring+DHCP+Server+on+Windows).
You have to say the DHCP, where your bootimage is and how it is named.
We are running at school such a solution with FOG in a Windows domain and it works without any problems.

You have only one thing to mention. There is an obsolete option, which I think it sounds like it has to do with PXE. We had the problem: If this "obsolete" option has some entries, the PXE-boot won't function.

From the Linux-PXE you can chainload the pxe of your WDS, if you want to deploy an image. Possibly it may also work the other way round, but I haven't any idea, how WDS works and so how you can edit the bootimage. The FOG-Service we use has an iPXE image, which imho can do anything you can imagine about PXE.